# Django ORM fetch data by 2 levels of foreign key relation

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=300, unique=True)
     description = models.CharField(max_length=2000)

class TemporaryUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='users'
    )

class QuestionSession(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='sessions',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )

class Question(models.Model):
    # stores the main json object with all required information
    description = JSONField(
        max_length=10000, blank=True, null=True, default=None
    )

    question_session = models.ForeignKey(
        QuestionSession,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='questions',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(
        Question,
        related_name='answers_list',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    answer = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    answered_by = models.ForeignKey(
        TemporaryUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='answers',
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None
    )
```

In a nutshell, my app contains questions, session is a collection of questions, and a project is a collection of sessions. All users are unique per project.

I can fetch all users and all answers within a specific project with the following:

```
TemporaryUser.objects.all().filter(project__id=project_id)
```

How can I do the same within a session? I don't really know how to do it, I need to filter users by session, is there a way how to do it with my relations?

Comment: Do you have a session id and you want to find the users that are associated with it through the relation chain user - project - session?

Comment: @EndreBoth exactly!

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean like:

```
TemporaryUser.objects.filter(project__sessions__id=id)
```

Comment: it fails with: Cannot query "QuestionSession object (1)": Must be "Project" instance.

Comment: but yup, I want something like this

Comment: Whoops  forgot to add the __id. Fixed

Comment: thanks for your answers! When I added id it returned: Related Field got invalid lookup: questionsession

Comment: it should be `sessions` due to `related_name` parameter in FK

Comment: I realize now that you've changed the related name. So it should be project__sessions__id=id

Comment: `__id` is not necessary BTW.

Comment: @Nidal still don't understand its behavior. It returns all users for the first project and ignores filtering by session.

Comment: Based on the way your class structure is, you cannot have different set of users across sessions in the same project. Your relationships are: "A project can have users" and "A project can have sessions" . Therefore, the users associated with a session will always be all the users in the project. If you expect otherwise, you may need to change your class/relationship structure.

Comment: You may need a pk on both objects. I've had trouble with this case before too.

Answer (score 0):

I think its cleaner to use [reverse relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/relations/) here:

```
session = QuestionSession.objects.first()
session.project.users.all()
# as User model has a FK with Project , and it has related_name="users"
```

You can use this in your template as well:

```
{% for qs in questionsessions %}  // questionsessions is the queryset of QuestionSession
     {% for user in qs.project.users.all %}
            {{ user.username }}
     {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch the users with only one query, the way to go is:

```
users = TemporaryUser.objects.filter(project__sessions=id)
```

However, if you want to fetch more data related to that session, maybe you should consider to fetch from the session itself (see [Following relationships backward](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)). Be cautious, as the number of queries to the database is not optimized.

```
session = Session.objects.get(pk=id)
users = session.project.users.all()
questions = session.questions.all()
```

You can use [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) if you want to make less queries. This could be very important if you are interested in fetching data for a list of sessions and not only one.